# Select2 disappearing, after adding dynamic form

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

i have a problem regarding select2, what happen is I have a dynamic form with few select2, but everytime I click the addNewItembtn the previous fields' select2 function will disappear.

here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            // set dropdown to select2
            $('#warehouse_id').select2();
            $('.product_id').select2();
            $('.unit_of_measure_id').select2();
            $('.product_type_id').select2();

            $('#addProductItemBtn').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                let productItems = $('tbody tr').length;
                let productItem = `
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select name="productItems[${productItems}][product_type_id]" id="product_type_id" class="form-control product_type_id">
                                <option value="">-- Product Type --</option>
                                @foreach ($productTypes as $productType)
                                    <option value="{{ $productType->id }}"
                                        @selected(old("productItems.{$loop->index}.product_type_id"))>
                                        {{ $productType->title }}
                                    </option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="productItems[${productItems}][product_id]" id="product_id" class="form-control product_id">
                                <option value="">-- Product --</option>
                                @foreach ($products as $product)
                                    <option value="{{ $product->id }}"
                                        @selected(old("productItems.{$loop->index}.product_id"))>
                                        {{ $product->product_name }}
                                    </option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="productItems[${productItems}][serial_number]" id="serial_number" class="form-control serial_number">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="brand" name="productItems[${productItems}][brand]" id="brand" class="form-control brand">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="productItems[${productItems}][unit_of_measure_id]" id="unit_of_measure_id" class="form-control unit_of_measure_id">
                                <option value="">-- UOM --</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="number" name="productItems[${productItems}][quantity]" id="quantity" class="form-control quantity" value="1">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="number" name="productItems[${productItems}][item_cost]" id="item_cost" class="form-control item_cost" value="0.00">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" class="deleteProductItemBtn">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                `;
                $('tbody').append(productItem);
                $('.product_id').select2();
                $('.unit_of_measure_id').select2();
                $('.product_type_id').select2();
            });

            $(document).on('click', '.deleteProductItemBtn', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            });
});
```

Upon loading the page, the select2 is still working
[first load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG25O.png)

After clicking the add new item button
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwBZ2.png)

You may notice that the select2 function did disappear after adding new fields. How can I make it that even after adding new fields the state of the previous page will remain. TIA

How can I make it that even after adding new fields the state of the previous page will remain. TIA

Comment: If I remove the lower part of the select2. after tbody, select2 will not take effect on the new added fields/forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is issue happening due to `id="product_type_id"` `id="product_id"`. The **ID** property should be unique so it's better to create dynamic ID's with row creation or simply remove the ID attribute from code. In other words you cannot need that for now.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    initSelect2();
    $('#addProductItemBtn').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let productItems = $('tbody tr').length;
        let productItem = `
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select name="productItems[${productItems}][product_type_id]" class="form-control product_type_id">
                            <option value="">-- Product Type --</option>
                            @foreach ($productTypes as $productType)
                                <option value="{{ $productType->id }}"
                                    @selected(old("productItems.{$loop->index}.product_type_id"))>
                                    {{ $productType->title }}
                                </option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="productItems[${productItems}][product_id]" class="form-control product_id">
                            <option value="">-- Product --</option>
                            @foreach ($products as $product)
                                <option value="{{ $product->id }}"
                                    @selected(old("productItems.{$loop->index}.product_id"))>
                                    {{ $product->product_name }}
                                </option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="productItems[${productItems}][serial_number]" id="serial_number" class="form-control serial_number">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="brand" name="productItems[${productItems}][brand]" id="brand" class="form-control brand">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="productItems[${productItems}][unit_of_measure_id]" class="form-control unit_of_measure_id">
                            <option value="">-- UOM --</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" name="productItems[${productItems}][quantity]" id="quantity" class="form-control quantity" value="1">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" name="productItems[${productItems}][item_cost]" id="item_cost" class="form-control item_cost" value="0.00">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" class="deleteProductItemBtn">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            `;
        $('tbody').append(productItem);

        initSelect2();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.deleteProductItemBtn', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });

    function initSelect2() {
        $('#warehouse_id').select2();
        $('.product_id').select2();
        $('.unit_of_measure_id').select2();
        $('.product_type_id').select2();
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<button id="addProductItemBtn">Add Item</button>
<table>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```